# how to reset a large number of class members at once, not in a destructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I have a class containing many members of a simple class type. More importantly, their number is growing as I go on with the development.

I need to be able to reset them all at once, and I'd like to do it without copy-pasting them. The code currently looks like:

```
typedef auto_ptr<odbc::PreparedStatement> Stmt;

class DbProxy {
private:
  void reset();

  Stmt a;
  Stmt b;
  Stmt c;
  // ... about 10 more
};

void DbProxy::reset()
{
  a.reset();
  b.reset();
  c.reset();
  // etc.
}
```

Obviously I don't like having to add every new member to the `reset()` function (just had a seg. fault for forgetting one).

What I intend to do is to collect them all into a structure and to allocate this structure under `auto_ptr`. So the code would look like this:

```
typedef auto_ptr<odbc::PreparedStatement> Stmt;

class DbProxy {
public:
  DbProxy(): stmts(new OdbcResources) {}
private:
  void reset() { stmts.reset(); }

  struct OdbcResources {
    Stmt a;
    Stmt b;
    Stmt c;
    // ... about 10 more
  };
  auto_ptr<OdbcResources> stmts;
};
```

Objects of DbProxy are not intended to be copied or copy-constructed, although I didn't bother to ensure this by making the assignment and copy-ctor private.

Do you see any problem with this approach? Do you have other suggestions?

**EDIT**

based on @DeadMG suggestion, what about this:

```
class DbProxy {
public:
  DbProxy();
private:
  enum Statements { SELECT1, SELECT2, INSERT, LAST };  // never mind the names

  void reset() { for (int i=0; i < LAST; i++) statement[i].reset(); }

  Stmt statements[LAST];
};
```

Comment: Can you put your `Stmt` objects into an array?  That way you can handle any arbitrary number of them.

Comment: why not a container of `shared_ptr<>` objects?

Comment: @Robert, not possible these are `auto_ptr` - which cannot be stored in a container

Comment: @Nim: They're all owned by the DbProxy class. What a waste of overhead to refcount them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the extra `auto_ptr` (each `Stmt` being an `auto_ptr` anyway), if you collect them in a single class you can reset them with a simple assignment. Unlike an array solution you still preserve their meaningful names.

Note that you can't use an unnamed temporary (e.g. `stmts = OdbcResources();`) as the generated copy assignment operator will take a non-`const` reference as the members (`auto_ptr`) cannot be assigned from non-`const` `auto_ptr`s.

```
class DbProxy {
public:
  DbProxy() : stmts() {}
private:
  void reset() { OdbcResources tmp; stmts = tmp; }

  struct OdbcResources {
    Stmt a;
    Stmt b;
    Stmt c;
    // ... about 10 more
  };
  OdbcResources stmts;
};
```

Comment: this is probably the simplest solution. Could you elaborate the second point, about the unnamed temporary?

Comment: @davka: The compiler can't generate a copy assignment operator with the signature `OdbcResources& operator=( const OdbcResources& )` because the memberwise assignment will fail for `auto_ptr` which takes a non-`const` reference in its copy assignment operator. The compiler has to generate a copy assignment operator with the signature `OdbcResources& operator=( OdbcResources& )`. Because you can't bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference `stmts = OdbcResources()` now won't compile.

Comment: BTW, if so, why am I able to compile a line like this: `aut_ptr<int> ip = auto_ptr<int>(new int);`?

Comment: @davka: Because `auto_ptr` has some implicit conversions to and from `auto_ptr_ref` that are specifically there to allow his sort of thing (otherwise assigning or constructing a `std::auto_ptr` from the `std::auto_ptr` returned by value from a function couldn't work and that's a very important use case). If you use containing structure: `struct X { explicit X(int* q):p(q){} std::auto_ptr<int> p; };` then you don't have any such implicit conversion helpers and you'll see that `X x = X(new int);` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use a statically sized array.

```
Stmt statements[10];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(statements) / sizeof(Stmt); i++)
    statements[i].reset();
```

Comment: thanks, it occurred to me, but there is an issue - currently they each have a meaningful name and are used in various methods provided by the DbProxy class. With an array, I will have to refer to them by `statements[3]` rather than `insertStmt`, which may cause errors and confusion.

Comment: I could perhaps use enum for this? please see the edit in my OP

Comment: @davka: You could simply make little helper functions. `Stmt& GetInsertStmt() { return statements[3]; }`. An enum will also do the job. `enum { InsertStmt = 0, UpdateStmt = 1 };` where you can pass the enum directly as an array index.

Comment: you could store an array of pointers to them instead; this would require you to setup the array pointers once though, eg in constructor: statements[0]=&a; statements[1]=&b; etc

Comment: @davka: Yes, that's exactly what I would do.

Comment: thanks! (I have to make this comment longer so that SO would accept it... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is crying out for a container - assuming `odbc::PreparedStatement` is copyable, simply have a vector of these in `DbProxy`

```
class DbProxy {
private:
  void reset() { resources.clear(); } // all vanish!

  vector<odbc::PreparedStatement> resources;
};
```

Else, `shared_ptr`

```
typedef shared_ptr<odbc::PreparedStatement> Stmt;
class DbProxy {
private:
  void reset() { resources.clear(); } // all vanish!

  vector<Stmt> resources;
};
```

Comment: thanks. The library I use (odbc++) only gives me a pointer to the `odbc::PreparedStatement` so I can't use the first option. The second is interesting, though.

Comment: If your library doesn't transfer ownership of the `odbc::PreparedStatement` to you, the second will also not work because both the `shared_ptr` and the library will think they have ownership.

Comment: @Mark B: not sure - their samples use `auto_ptr` that deletes the pointer when goes out of scope, so I assume they do transfer the ownership (sort of, anyway, because when I reset the connection the statement belongs to, I get seg. fault when trying to use/delete the statement. So it looks like a shared ownership...)

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with this type of approach.
This looks like the "Private Implementation" idiom. You can be interested in the [details](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

my2c

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simply copy in a default copy:

```
void reset() { *this = DbProxy(); }
```

Comment: this is interesting, but looks a bit brutal, isn't it? Anyway it assumes that I have nothing in the class **but** those statements.

Comment: Yes, but what about `stmts.reset(new OdbcResources);` to just reset the prepared statements to default constructed items?